# Neo4j java api to merge Oracle results?

Tags: neo4j

Migrating from MySQL to neo4j, need MERGE command in java api?
Like CREATE node, in have we do `db.createNode()`. Similarly, something like `db.Merge` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why?

```
String query = "MERGE (n:Foo {id:{id}}) ON CREATE SET n += {data}";
db.execute(query, map("id",id, "data", mapOfProperties));
```

There is no MERGE in the Java API.

Comment: Hi Michael, could give me an example of how do we pass mysql resultset's some of the column's name as propertyName and column's value as propertyValue to MERGE command. As I am not sure of the which column will go as property name at runtime.

Comment: Also, if you could look at this issue -- "import mysql database to neo4j using java takes about 2 hours for writing 100K nodes with 5 properties" .....and respond to me...it would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [neo4j Java Developer Reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-get-or-create):

> The preferred way to get or create a unique node is to use unique
>   constraints and Cypher. See [Get or create unique node using Cypher and unique constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create) for more information.

The link in the above quote leads to an example of how to create a unique constraint and also an example of merging.